# Classification Algorithms with Connected Pre-Images/Classification Boundaries

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm

Given some function $f:\mathbb{R}^d \to \{0,1\}$, let us assume that $f^{-1}(\{0\})$, as well as $f^{-1}(\{1\})$ are connected, and at least one is an   **open**
set. Is there a classification algorithm to estimate $f$ from a collection of data $\{(x_1,y_1), \cdots, (x_n,y_n)\}$, such that such an algorithm can

1. Accomodate non-linear separation
2. Force (or at least guarantee with high probability) that its classification regions are also connected sets?

If not, can currently existing algorithms be modified to reach such a goal? (e.g., SVM with a low-degree polynomial kernel and large regularization constant). Perhaps another way to consider this would be - how do we turn the topological notion of connectedness into some sort of criteria or constraint for optimization?

Comment: Some comments: (1) connectedness of $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ does not imply $f^{-1}(\{1\})$ is connected.  (2) It might be worthwhile questioning criterion (2), because conceivably a procedure that doesn't necessarily return connected sets could perform much better than other procedures according to a relevant loss function.  (3) Given any distributional assumption for the data, you can modify any procedure that doesn't meet (2) to return connected sets by changing its values on a set of probability zero.  These suggest the question is unlikely to yield useful answers.

Comment: Thanks for the correction on (1) @whuber, I was thinking of the case of $\mathbb{R}^2$ where one of the sets was simply connected and hence its complement is also connected.